# Plot of the L0 norm penalty function in matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex

I am interested to plot the `L0-norm` penalty function in matlab.

In fact, I know that the `L0-norm` of a vector **x**, ||**x**||_0, returns a value which designates the total number of nonzero elements in **x**. In other terms, ||**x**||_0 = #(i | xi !=0).

For example, for the L1-norm of **x**, it returns the sum of the absolute values of the elements in **x**. The matlab code to plot the L_1 norm penalty function is:

```
clear all;
clc;

x = [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
penal = zeros (length(x),1);
lambda = 2; % the tuning parameter
for ii = 1 : length(x)
penal(ii) = lambda*abs(x(ii));
end
figure
plot(x(:), penal(:), 'r');
```

But now what about the L_0 norm??

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line inside the for loop with the following:

```
penal(ii) = lambda*(x(ii) ~= 0);
```

This assigns a penalty of **lambda** for all non-zero values in the vector **x**.

Comment: BTW, you could avoid `for` loop by using `penal = lambda*(x ~= 0);`, or `penal = lambda*abs(x);`. This would be much more efficient for high dimensional vectors.

Comment: Thank you so much!